# xmlbeans - set content of a complex type

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

My xsd file contains:

```
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Book">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="author" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
```

With xmlbeans, I can set the attributes easily using:

```
    Book book= books.addNewBook();
    book.setTitle("The Lady and a Little Dog");
```

I know that I can use newCursor() to set the content of the element, but is this the best way?

```
object.newCursor().setTextValue(builer.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question.

I think your XSD will give you Java classes to produce XML like this:

```
<book author="Fred" title="The Lady and a Little Dog" />
```

Do you mean you want to set the "inner" text within an XML element, so you end up with XML like this?

```
<book>
  <author>Fred</author>
  <title>The Lady and a Little Dog</title>
</book>
```

If so, change your XSD to this, to use nested elements rather than attributes:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Book">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

Then you'll simply be able to do:

```
Book book= books.addNewBook();
book.setAuthor("Fred");
book.setTitle("The Lady and a Little Dog");
```

---

**UPDATE**

OK - I understand now.

Try this:

```
<xs:element name="Book"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="author" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>    
</xs:element>
```

And then:

```
    Book book1 = books.addNewBook();
    book1.setAuthor("Fred");
    book1.setTitle("The Lady and a Little Dog");
    book1.setStringValue("This is some text");

    Book book2 = books.addNewBook();
    book2.setAuthor("Jack");
    book2.setTitle("The Man and a Little Cat");
    book2.setStringValue("This is some more text");
```

Which should give XML like this, which I think is what you want:

```
<Book author="Fred" title="The Lady and a Little Dog">This is some text</Book>
<Book author="Jack" title="The Man and a Little Cat">This is some more text</Book>
```

Comment: This is what I would like my xml to look like:


<book author="Fred" title="The Lady and a Little Dog" >This is some text</book>


How can I put the "This is some text" bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but the best way to set the value of attributes or elements using XMLBeans is to use the XMLBeans-generated getters and setters.

Maybe a little more context for your cursor question would be helpful.